# Looping through routes to get individual value and push it to a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a component that fills with links using routes to different components of my website. some of these links open the same component. I am looping through the data and setting a route to each one of the links like this.

```
<li *ngFor="let ql of quickLinks" [routerLink]="ql.iTorahRoute" routerLinkActive="active" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center"
class="dropdown-item" (click)="onClick()">{{ ql.Title }}</li>
```

my problem is when I click on a route that opens the same component it does not refresh automatically so I set a click event (the onClick() to run) which runs this snippet which works.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefershComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
    this.router.navigate([this.text]));
```

My problem is I cannot figure out how to push [routerLink]="ql.iTorahRoute" to update this.text (this should be the route) with each individual route on click

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by pushing a parameter to the function

```
(click)="onClick(ql)"
```

then just grabbing that parameter in my typescript file

```
onClick(quickLinks){
 let currentRoute = quickLinks.linkRoute
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefershComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
 this.router.navigate([currentRoute]));
```

}